# How can I get a sorted array of selected verts in blender python

Tags: python, blender

I have a loop of vertices selected in blender and I want to move each vertex to the position of its neighbour anti-clockwise.

```
def marchVerticesACW():
    ob = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
    mesh = ob.data
    verts = [i.index for i in bpy.context.active_object.data.vertices if i.select]
    covar=mesh.vertices[verts[0]].co
    cx=covar.x
    cy=covar.y
    cz=covar.z
    for x in range(len(verts)-1):
        mesh.vertices[verts[x]].co=mesh.vertices[verts[x+1]].co
    mesh.vertices[verts[len(verts)-1]].co.x=cx
    mesh.vertices[verts[len(verts)-1]].co.y=cy
    mesh.vertices[verts[len(verts)-1]].co.z=cz
```

works if the vertices happen to appear in the list in the right order but they don't always. is there a way to sort the list if it happens to be out of sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked it out, based on the fact that each vert in the loop is joined to the next by an edge, so starting from any vert I just search the selected edges for the first that has that vertex at one end, make a note of the next vert on that edge, remove the edge from the collection then look for the edge that has the new vert at one end. It only works for closed loops and I haven't put in any error handling / checking but thought the basic idea might help someone else

```
import bpy
import bmesh


def OrderSelectedVerts(_bm):
    edge=_edges[0]
    startvert=edge.verts[0]
    _edges.remove(edge)
    _orderedVerts=[]
    _orderedVerts.append(startvert)
    while len(_edges)>0:
        startvert=GetNextVert(startvert)
        if startvert is not None:
            _orderedVerts.append(startvert)
    return _orderedVerts

def GetNextVert(sv):
    for e in _edges:
        if e.verts[0]==sv or e.verts[1]==sv:
            if e.verts[0]==sv:
                d=e.verts[1]
            else:
                d=e.verts[0]
            _edges.remove(e)
            return d


# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data


# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
_edges=[i for i in bm.edges if i.select]

#Get the selected verts in order
orderedVerts=OrderSelectedVerts(bm)

#Use the ordered verts


#Update the bmesh
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```